# perl regex to remove dashes

Tags: regex, perl

I have some files I am processing, and I would like to remove the dashes from the non date fields.

I came  up with `s/([^0-9]+)-([^0-9]+)/$1 $2/g` but that only works if there is one dash only in the string, or I should say it will only remove one dash.

So lets say I have:

```
 2014-05-01
 this-and
 this-and-that
 this-and-that-and-that-too
 2015-01-01
```

What regex would I use to produce

```
 2014-05-01
 this and
 this and that
 this and that and that too
 2015-01-01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [look around](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) :

```
$ perl -pe 's/
    (?<!\d)    # a negative look-behind with a digit: \d
    -          # a dash, literal 
    (?!\d)     # a negative look-ahead  with a digit: \d
/ /gx' file
```

#### OUTPUT

```
 2014-05-01
 this and
 this and that
 this and that and that too
 2015-01-01
```

Look around are some assertions to ensure that there's no digit (in this case) around `-`. A look around don't make any capture, it's really just there to test assertions. It's a good tool to have near you.

Check :

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444
http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Thanks @sputnik, can you explain this in a bit more detail, i.e. the look arounds?

Comment: Added a bit of explanations

Comment: Thanks, the lookbehinds/lookaheads are sweet!

Answer (score 6):

**Don't do it with one regex.**  There is no requirement that a single regex must contain all of your code's logic.

Use one regex to see if it's a date, and then a second one to do your transformation.  It will be much clearer to the reader (that's you, in the future) if you split it up into two.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

while ( my $str = <DATA>) {
    chomp $str;
    my $old = $str;
    if ( $str !~ /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/ ) {  # First regex to see if it's a date
        $str =~ s/-/ /g;                    # Second regex to do the transformation
    }
    print "$old\n$str\n\n";
}
__DATA__
2014-05-01
this-and
this-and-that
this-and-that-and-that-too
2015-01-01
```

Running that gives you:

```
2014-05-01
2014-05-01

this-and
this and

this-and-that
this and that

this-and-that-and-that-too
this and that and that too

2015-01-01
2015-01-01
```

Answer (score 1):

Lose the `+` - it's catching the string up until the last `-`, including any previous `-` characters:

```
s/([^0-9]|^)-+([^0-9]|$)/$1 $2/g;
```

Example: https://ideone.com/r2CI7v

Comment: This will fail for `--`.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your program receives each field separately in the `$_` variable, all you need is

```
tr/-/ / if /[^-\d]/
```

Comment: Im reading in a comma delimited file, so I receive the whole line as $_, not field by field.

Comment: Then you should split it into fields using `Text::CSV` first. It is much simpler than allowing for all the complexities of CSV data as well as changing some of the hyphens to spaces, especially because `this and that` needs to be in double-quotes, whereas `this-and-that` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
$line =~ s/(\D)-/$1 /g;
```

Comment: Ah match any nondigit followed by a dash, replace with non digit and space?

Comment: Except for cases like `5-a-dime chews`

Comment: @tman, yes. It will work ONLY if you have entries like yours. For Borodin's case - NO

Answer (score 0):

As I explained in a comment, you really need to use [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV) to split each record into fields *before* you edit the data. That's because data that contain whitespace need to be enclosed in double quotes, so a field like `this-and-that` will start out without spaces, but needs them added when the hyphens are translated to spaces.

This program shows a simple example that uses your own data.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({eol => $/});

while (my $row = $csv->getline(\*DATA)) {
  for (@$row) {
    tr/-/ / unless /^\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d$/;
  }
  $csv->print (\*STDOUT, $row);
}

__DATA__
2014-05-01,this-and-that,this-and-that,this-and-that-and-that-too,2015-01-01
```

**output**

```
2014-05-01,"this and that","this and that","this and that and that too",2015-01-01
```